# Iterator as an integer

Tags: java, compiler-errors, iterator

As far as I know, an Iterator is an object which type is defined during its declaration but which also comes with two other methods: `hasNext()` and `next()`.
So, besides those two methods, if I write `Iterator<Integer> iterator`, then iterator is supposed to behave like an Integer object.
However, when I try to use `iterator.intValue()`, I get an error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method intValue() is undefined for the type Class<capture#1-of ? extends Iterator>
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block
```

Here is the full code:

```
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = content.iterator(); //content is a HashSet<Integer> object
    System.out.println(iterator.intValue());

    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        iterator.next();
        System.out.println(iterator);

    }
```

Comment: there is no intValue() method on Iterator. you can use `if( iterator.hasNext() ) { iterator.next().intValue() }`

Comment: "iterator is supposed to behave like an Integer object"  
No, that is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the Integer from the iterator, then print that Integer:

```
Integer i = iterator.next();
System.out.println(i);
```

An Iterator is an iterator for integers, it doesn't behave like an integer. The next method will return an Integer.

Answer (score 4):

No, an `Iterator<T>` does not act like a `T` - its `next()` method, however, **returns a T value**. I.e.:

```
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    Integer myInteger = iterator.next();
    int myInt = myInteger.intValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An Iterator is not an Integer, though it might give you one if you call `next()`  Instead of calling the Iterator directly is usually better to use a for-each loop which was added to Java 5.0 in 2006.

```
for(int n : content) //content is a HashSet<Integer> object
    System.out.println(n);
```

From Java 8 you can use the forEach method.

```
content.forEach(System.out::println);
```